# Why would job_start()'s close_cb sometimes not be called?

Tags: job-control

I have a `job_start()` call like this:

```
let options = {
      \ 'stdoutbuffer': [],
      \ 'handler': a:handler,
      \ }
let command = s:build_command(a:cmd)
let s:job = job_start(command, {
      \ 'out_cb':   function('s:on_stdout_vim', options),
      \ 'close_cb': function('s:on_close_vim', options),
      \ 'exit_cb':  function('s:on_exit_vim', options)
      \ })
```

The external command being run is `ps -axco command`.

Normally when the job runs, the `out_cb` is invoked multiple times, then the `close_cb` once, and finally the `exit_cb` once.

However when my code is invoked twice in rapid succession the first job's `close_cb` is never invoked.  I haven't been able to figure out why.

This is a problem because the job result is handled in my `close_cb` handler (I only added an `exit_cb` to try to debug this problem).  So if the `close_cb` handler isn't invoked the result of the job is lost.

The docs says that `exit_cb` is called when the job ends and `close_cb` is called when the channel is closed.  So `exit_cb` sounds more appropriate because I care about the job, not the underlying channel.

However the `exit_cb` docs also say that:

> data can be buffered, callbacks may still be called after the process ends.

I *think* that's saying that `out_cb` can be called after `exit_cb`.  If so, it would suggest that I can't rely on `exit_cb` to know when I have everything produced by the job on stdout.

Furthermore the `close_cb` docs say that:

> Vim will invoke callbacks that handle data before invoking close_cb

Which sounds like I can rely on having all the data when `close_cb` is invoked.  And this is why I'm using `close_cb` instead of `exit_cb` to act on the job's result.  Except `close_cb` doesn't get invoked when this other plugin's job is around.

Am I right to use `close_cb` not `exit_cb`?  If so, why would it not be invoked?  When would it be right to use `exit_cb`?

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example which exhibits the reported behavior?  Does it help if you handle the job result in the `exit_cb` handler, and write `sleep 1m` at the top (to give some time to pending callbacks)?

Comment: I can reproduce this consistently with the two plugins, but haven't been able to come up with a minimal example.  Handling the result in `exit_cb` would work here, though the 1ms sleep is a bit arbitrary, but I'd like to understand why `close_cb` doesn't get called.

Comment: I had some idea as to what is causing the issue, but without a minimal example, I can't be sure.  Anyway, see [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22597/17449).  `sleep 1m` is not that arbitrary; it's the least amount of time Vim can sleep, and in my experience, it's enough for all pending callbacks to have been processed.

Comment: I store a reference to each job in a dictionary; keys are incrementing ids and values are jobs.  `sleep 1m` (or even `10m` doesn't help).  I'll keep trying to produce a minimal example.

Comment: Here's a [gist of the code](https://gist.github.com/airblade/4585556f713f0f9cc537d14054056a3b).

Comment: I sidestepped the problem by replacing my `close_cb` with an `exit_cb` and sleeping at the top of the `exit_cb` to allow any buffered data to reach the `out_cb`.  I still don't know why the channel gets stuck in a "pre-closing" state until ctrl-c unblocks it.